# validating against list of values in hibernate validator

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

We are using hibernate validator 5.0.1. We have a huge form, having 20 different selects. All the list of values are more or less static (known at compile time). Some of the list of values are really huge (eg. list of countries).

AFAIK, there is no builtin constraint in HV for validating a field against a list of strings. So, we  have written a custom validator for same. What is the best approach for validating an input against say 1000 values in a given list? Also, we need the ability to give different message per list that failed. For eg. ("Invalid country", "invalid state", etc).

Comment: Can you share the code for your custom constraint. If the constraint keeps a list of these values, the easiest is of course to call list#constains(validatedValue). You can define the message as part of the constraint usage site via the message parameter or you can customize the message via the ConstraintValidatorContext object passed to isValid in your custom constraint validator.